# Website with shared user database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-ec2

I have around 4 websites under a parent website (kind of like stackExchange.). I would like my user to register at one website and has access to all the websites. Any known good solutions to this?

My idea: Every server has its own database. If someone created an account, it curls another 3 servers and do the validation. If it's validated, create the user in all 4 databases.

Is there a better way to do this? Or is there an issue to my solution? Thanks!

Comment: Essentially what you are trying to do is build a single sign on system. If you are not careful about how you implement this though, you can easily create security holes in your site.

Comment: If you tell us what technology you are using to implement your websites, we might recommend you a good SSO add-on

Comment: @datasage can u be more specific? say that i just have a system so every time a user register one one site, it curl another 3 to create the username/or do the validation? Any problems with this? Thanks!

Comment: @UriAgassi Well we are using PHP(Yii)+MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

Single Sign On (SSO) is a fairly complex problem, and I would suggest that won't try to re-invent the wheel. Find a library which supports it.

You can try looking at this [PHP based SSO solution](http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/):

> I’ve written a simple single sign-on solution (400 lines of code),
>   which works by linking sessions. This solutions works for normal
>   websites as well as AJAX sites.